# Meromorphic function with a removable singularity and a few poles

Tags: complex-analysis, limits, meromorphic-functions

Here is the question:

Let $f$ be a meromorhic function on $\mathbb{C}$, having poles at the following three points: $z=5$, $z=1+3i$ and $z=3-4i$.  Also, let $f$ have one removable singularity at $z=3$.  For the following, find the value or explain why not enough information is given to find the quantity.

a) $\lim_{z\rightarrow5}|f(z)|$

b) $\lim_{z\rightarrow1+2i}(z-1-2i)f(z)$

c) $\lim_{z\rightarrow\infty}|f(z)|$

My thoughts:

I was wondering if I would be able to write $f$ as a rational function, such as $f(z)=\frac{(z-3)^m}{(z-3)^m(z-5)^n(z-(1+3i))^k(z-(3-4i))^l}$ for $m, n, k, l\in\mathbb{Z^{+}}$?  This just doesn't feel right, because I am not really sure how this would help me do $(a)$ or $(b)$.
For $(c)$, wouldn't the limit just be $0$ (I suppose if I can write $f$ in the above form).
My other idea was to try and write $f$ as a Laurent series, but I am not quite sure how to "give" $f$ the removable singularity as well as all the poles.  I suppose I could try and think of a Laurent series that would satisfy the conditions, prove that it satisfies the conditions, and then try and find $(a), (b), (c)$, but I am not sure if this would be the most efficient way, or if there would be another way.  I appreciate any ideas, thoughts, etc.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the fact that if $f:\mathbb C\backslash S\to\mathbb C$ is a function satisfying your given conditions, where $S$ is the set containing the four given singularities, and $g$ an entire function, then $\tilde f:=f+g$ also satisfies the given conditions, while possibly resulting in different limits. I recommend not to try to find a general term describing your function, and instead relying on general facts about meromorphic functions and their singularities.

a) There's a theorem which says that an isolated singularity $z_0$ is a pole iff $\lim_{z\to z_0}\vert f(z)\vert=\infty$.

b) I think you're missing a $z$. And maybe you wanted to make it 3, not 2? Is it supposed to be $\lim_{z\to(1+3\mathrm i)}(z-1-3\mathrm i)f(z)$? If yes, remember the definition of the order of a pole, and consider that you don't know the order.

c) You found an example where this limit is $0$ (though you should really remove the numerator in your fraction for it to work). Now add an arbitrary entire function as I did above. Is the limit still $0$?

Comment: Okay...
So, $(a)$ becomes trivial with that theorem.  I am trying to find the theorem in Ahlfors (if it is in there), but I am probably overlooking it somewhere.
For $(b)$, I was supposed to have a $z$ in there, and I edited the original problem, but it really is supposed to be as is typed in OP.  Because of that, I am thinking that we don't have enough information to determine the quantity (which is a possibility).
For $(c)$, I suppose we could create an entire function such that its limit isn't $0$ but still satisfies the assumptions, so would we not have enough information to answer c?

Comment: You're right about (c), but (b) needs some tweaking. In the case that it's actually supposed to be a 2, you have the product of two functions $f(z)$ and $z-1-2\mathrm i$ which are both continuous in $1+2\mathrm i$. It follows that the product is also continuous, which tells us something about the value it attains at $1+2\mathrm i$.

Comment: So would $(b)$ just be $0$ then since $z-1-2i$ would go to $0$ as $z\rightarrow 1+2i$?

Comment: Yes, it would be.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what about if b happened to be as in your first comment?   Thank you so much!

Comment: Then $f$ would not be continuous at the point we're approaching, so this argument wouldn't work. In fact, there would be no way to tell the limit. If the singularity were of order 1, then the singularity of $(z-1-3\mathrm i)f(z)$ would be removable with limit not equal to 0 (as per the definition of the order of a pole). But if it were of higher order, then $(z-1-3\mathrm i)f(z)$ would still have a pole, so the limit would be $\infty$.

Comment: Okay, I see.  Thank you!  For this problem, is there any other neat sort of questions that you could see dealing with poles, singularities, limits, etc.? I just want to make sure that I am thinking of it the right way.   Thank you!

Comment: Essentially any question dealing with limits around singularities which can be answered by either of the three theorems: 1. $z_0$ is removable iff $f$ is bounded in a neighborhood of $z_0$. 2. $z_0$ is pole iff $\lim_{z\to z_0}\vert f(z)\vert=\infty$, 3. $z_0$ is essential iff the image of any neighborhood of $z_0$ under $f$ is dense in $\mathbb C$.   Also, $z_0$ is a pole of order $k$ iff $(z-z_0)^kf(z)$ has a removable singularity at $z_0$ with non-zero limit. You might want to think about situations where these would (not) help finding a particular limit yourself to improve understanding.

Comment: Very good.  I will do that!  Thank you so much!